# Swig tags not working in the index file when not in the same folder as other views

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, swig-template

I've got an app with the following structure:

```
- app
  - views
      pages
      includes
  - index.html
```

In my app I use this:

```
if (env === 'development' || env === 'test') {

  swig.setDefaults({
    cache: false
  });
}

app.engine('html', swig.renderFile);
app.set('views', [config.root + '/tmp', config.root + '/tmp/views/includes', config.root + '/tmp/views/pages']);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
```

**Index.html:**

```
{% include 'includes/head.html' %}
```

The problem that occurs however is that any swig tags in the `index.html` file isn't working, it just prints them out as a string. If I move the index file inside the `views` folder it works though.

I can't find any solutions to this, what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

maybe try prepending the names of the folders in `app.set('views'...` with `__dirname`?